# WP - function working on my localhost(MAC) but in windows server live not working Wordpress 4.1.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I want all categories in one page with filter .I find a solution . this is working fine in my localhost but in live (Windows server) not working.

Here is this function in functions.php:

```
/**
 * Create terms list.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 *
 * @param array $args
 *
 * @return string
 */
function clpr_terms_list( $args = array() ) {

    $defaults = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'exclude' => array(),
        'menu' => true,
        'count' => true,
        'top_link' => true,
        'class' => 'terms',
    );

    $options = wp_parse_args( (array) $args, $defaults );
    $options = apply_filters( 'clpr_terms_list_args', $options );

    $terms = get_terms( $options['taxonomy'], array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'child_of' => 0, 'pad_counts' => 0, 'app_pad_counts' => 1 ) );

    $navigation = '';
    $list = '';
    $groups = array();

    if ( empty( $terms ) || ! is_array( $terms ) )
        return html( 'p', __( 'Sorry, but no terms were found.', 'Couponize' ) );

    // unset child terms
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value->parent != 0 )
            unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $letter = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $term->name, 0, 1 ) );
        if ( is_numeric( $letter ) )
            $letter = '#';

        if ( ! empty( $letter ) )
            $groups[ $letter ][] = $term;
    }

    if ( empty( $groups ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $groups as $letter => $terms ) {
        $old_list = $list;
        $old_navigation = $navigation;
        $letter_items = false;

        $letter = apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter );
        $letter_id = ( preg_match( '/\p{L}/', $letter ) ) ? $letter : substr( md5( $letter ), 0, 5 ); // hash special chars
        $navigation .= html_link( '#' . $options['class'] . '-' . $letter_id, $letter );
        $top_link = ( $options['top_link'] ) ? html_link( '#top', __( 'Top', 'Couponize' ) . ' &uarr;' ) : '';

        $list .= '<h2 class="' . $options['class'] . '" id="' . $options['class'] . '-' . $letter_id . '">' . $letter . $top_link . '</h2>';
        $list .= '<ul class="' . $options['class'] . '">';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $options['exclude'] ) )
                continue;

            $letter_items = true;
            $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name );
            $link = html_link( get_term_link( $term, $options['taxonomy'] ), $name );
            $count = ( $options['count'] ) ? ' (' . intval( $term->count ) . ')' : '';

            $list .= html( 'li', $link . $count );
        }

        $list .= '</ul>';

        if ( ! $letter_items ) {
            $list = $old_list;
            $navigation = $old_navigation;
        }
    }

    $navigation = html( 'div class="grouplinks"', $navigation );

    if ( $options['menu'] )
        $list = $navigation . $list;

    return $list;
}


/**
 * Create categories list.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 *
 * @return string
 */
function clpr_categories_list() {
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'class' => 'categories',
    );

    return clpr_terms_list( $args );
}

/**
 * Create stores list.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 *
 * @return string
 */
function clpr_stores_list() {
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'class' => 'stores',
    );

    return clpr_terms_list( $args );
}
```

I am trying to echo this function in template file.

```
<?php echo clpr_stores_list(); ?>
```

But not working. please help me.

Thanks

Comment: turn your error reporting on and see if you get any error. Also double check if this code is really getting called. You can do so by putting a `die` statement inside the function.

Comment: I have turned on error reporting . But no error showing .

Comment: in your `clpr_strores_list();` function put a `die` statement.

Comment: How to put die statement ?

Comment: Which PHP and Apache/IIS versions are you running on each environment? Could you also give us a list of PHP extensions running on each environment.

Comment: `function clpr_stores_list() {  die('Checking'); }`

Comment: In my Localhost, php 5.6.5 and windows server php 5.6 (may be php 5.6.5 . How to check php version from wp)

Comment: when i put die('working'); it showing working in this page. but when i put die(clpr_terms_list( $args )); it's showing nothing

Comment: localhost php version 5.6.5 and windows server php version 5.6.6